# SQL Studio - "Modify Stored Procedure" Script Errors

Tags: ssms

In MS SQL Server Management Studio 2005:

If you have the setting Tools|Options|Scripting|"Include IF NOT EXISTS clause" set to true, modifying a stored procedure will create a strange script that doesn't even work. It looks something like the following: (ellipsis used for brevity)

```
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 IF NOT EXISTS [...]
 BEGIN
 EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[p_Procedure]
 [...]
 '
 END
```

This obviously doesn't work because the only way the ALTER statement is called, is if the stored procedure DOESN'T exist.

The question is thus: **is there any way of changing this generated code**? A template out there somewhere (this doesn't seem to be related to the build in Templating tools)?

(A slight explanation for this behavior: scripting a CREATE statement generates the same code in which the IF NOT EXISTS makes more sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues on this topic on MS-feedback site.
Here are one:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=260519

Here are one comment on that issue (from the bottom of the page linked above):

> In SQL2000, the approach was If
>   exists, DROP followed by a CREATE.
>   This worekd flawlessly and covered all
>   cases. It wored so well that we built
>   our deployment off of this scripting
>   model. Since SQl2005 entered our
>   world, we have had manual, cumbersome
>   workarounds to replace the automated
>   scripting that was lost in the move to
>   SQL2000.
>
> Please do readd the If exists, DROP
>   followed by a CREATE approac. It was
>   great the way